# style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found

Tags: java, android, xml

I opened the android project, i got this error, how do i fix it?

Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
/Users/Ren/Desktop/17live/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
Error:(515, 5) style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found
Error:(515, 5) style attribute '@android:attr/windowExitAnimation' not found
Error:(577, 5) style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found
Error:(577, 5) style attribute '@android:attr/windowExitAnimation' not found
Error:/Users/Ren/Desktop/17live/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3534 style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found
Error:/Users/Ren/Desktop/17live/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3796 style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found
Error:failed linking references
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 13s
>   Information:10 errors
>   Information:1 warning
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Why off topic???

Answer (score 37):

go to res/style.xml and you can remove @ before android and if there is any .xml remove the .xml and rebuilt your project. Your style should look something like this something like this

```
<item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_down_dialog</item>
```

Comment: thanks guys i get how to fix it now, but it's not add @, it's delete @, it working, my project is run up