# android studio 3.0 error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I had followed steps of migrating to android studio 3.0 updgradation.

build.gradle

```
    flavorDimensions 'dimensionless'
```

> D:\R\merchant\projapp\popuplibrary\build\intermediates\bundles\debug\res\values\values.xml
>   Error:(28, 5) error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found.
>   C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\f7bb6db2aa55d14683d1c9ddd8d49e03\res\values\values.xml
>   Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>   
> Error:Execution failed for task ':popuplibrary:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
>   Failed to execute aapt

Facing same issue but it is apccompat library also creating issue in my case.

[style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45767077/style-attribute-androidattr-windowenteranimation-not-found)

gradlewrapper:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

build.gradle app:

```
   productFlavors {
                dev {
                    applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
                    versionName "1.0"
                    versionNameSuffix '-dev'
                    }
qa {
                    applicationIdSuffix '.qa'
                    versionName "1.0"
                    versionNameSuffix '-qa'
                    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Butter Knife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'

    compile project(':popuplibrary')
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your  gradle.properties , gradle.app ?

Comment: updated in question

Comment: Thanks, also build.gradle (app) let me check your dependencies and your implementation for flavors.

Answer (score 28):

This issue is described in the [migration guide for Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#known_issues).

> #### Incorrect use of @ resource reference symbols
>
> AAPT2 now throws build errors when you omit or incorrectly place resource reference symbols (`@`). For example, consider if you omit the symbol when specifying a style attribute, as shown below:
>
> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
>   ...
>   <!-- Note the missing '@' symbol when specifying the resource type. -->
>   <item name="colorPrimary">color/colorPrimary</item>
> </style>
> ```
>
> When building the module, AAPT2 now throws the following build error:
>
> ```
> ERROR: expected color but got (raw string) color/colorPrimary
> ```
>
> Additionally, consider if you incorrectly include the symbol when accessing a resource from the android namespace, as shown below:
>
> ```
> ...
> <!-- When referencing resources from the 'android' namespace, omit the '@' symbol. -->
> <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation"/>
> ```
>
> When building the module, AAPT2 now throws the following build error:
>
> ```
> Error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found
> ```

If you didn't make the mistake described in second half, then perhaps an old version of appcompat-v7 is to blame.

#### The good

Update to newer support libraries, pick 25.4.0 or 26.1.0 or 27.0.0. Make sure you match `compileSdkVersion`.

Note: If you choose to update to something older than 27.0.0 you may run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582430).

#### The bad

If for some reason you're stuck with 25.3.1 or older you can [disable AAPT2](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html).

> If you are experiencing issues while using AAPT2, you can disable it by setting `android.enableAapt2=false` in your `gradle.properties` file and restarting the Gradle daemon by running `./gradlew --stop` from the command line.

Comment: gradle.properties or gradle.wrapper.properties

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the **subprojects{}** block in android/build.gradle and set the recent android compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion used in the main project so that the subprojects use these versions too.

*Example*

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
            }
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `android.enableAapt2=false` in the `gradle.properties` file fixes this issue.

Comment: WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I removed/updated `thebuildToolsVersion "27.0.3"` in build.gradle.