# Android : Difference between DataBinding and ViewBinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

We are using [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) since Jetpack release. Android documentation indicates that [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) was added in **Android Studio 3.6 Canary 11+.**

I read the documentation but its looks similar to **DataBinding.**

Can anyone explain what's the difference between these two concepts?

Comment: Roughly speaking, view binding is a subset of data binding. You do not get the data binding expressions, but you do get the generated binding class that you can use to handle the `findViewById()` calls and give you type-safe and null-safe access to the widgets from the layout.

Comment: @CommonsWare What is the advantage of using ViewBinding if DataBinding does all of that and more?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: Data binding slows the build process. The build process for view binding is not as bad.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding):

#### ViewBinding

Only binding views to code.

#### DataBinding

Binding data (from code) to views + ViewBinding (Binding views to code)

There are three important differences

1. With view binding, the layouts do not need a layout tag
2. You can't use viewbinding to bind layouts with data in xml
   (No binding expressions, no BindingAdapters nor two-way binding with viewbinding)
3. The main advantages of viewbinding are speed and  efficiency. It has a shorter build time because it avoids the overhead and performance issues associated with databinding due to annotation processors affecting databinding's build time.

In short, there is nothing viewbinding can do that databinding cannot do (though at cost of longer build times) and there are a lot databinding can do that viewbinding can"t

Comment: What is the biggest advantage of ViewBinding?

Comment: Speed and efficiency

Comment: Okay, just suggest me one thing. What should I use? or should I use both? I'm talking about any general project. And yes I want to use MVVM structure. Please suggest.

Comment: You can use VIEWBINDING to replace findviewbyid() effectively. If your project is however more complex and you need added 'sugar' and features ( like binding data to views, binding adapters e.t.c), use DATABINDING.

Comment: You also don't need to use both. If you are using DATABINDING, there is no need adding VIEWBINDING

Comment: Everyone states, that ViewBinding does not use annotation processing, but as you may see it uses code generation still. What is the difference between those two and why annotation processing is so much worse?

Answer (score 52):

**ViewBinding VS Databinding**

Here is why I wanted to explain `ViewBinding` and `DataBinding` together.
[image]

As you can see, `ViewBinding` is a sort of subset of `DataBinding` libraries which means `ViewBinding` and `DataBiding` can do the same jobs in terms of binding layouts. And it would also mean with `DataBinding`, you might not need `ViewBinding` cause it will do what `ViewBinding` is supposed to do and also provide a bit of an extra functionalities such as 2way binding, and using variables in `XML` files.

**Then, this can lead to a question**

> "Then let's just use `DataBinding` as it sounds much more fancy!"

Hold on. As much as it sounds fancy, it is a pretty heavy loaded library which might cause a longer compile time. So if you are not going to use `DataBinding` only functionalities then might be better to consider `ViewBinding` as it does have some advantages in terms of build time and apk size.

[For more detail read this article](https://dev.to/ham8821/android-accessing-view-now-what-1jkg)

Answer (score 14):

By the official definitions,

View binding allows us to more easily write code that interacts with views. Once view binding is enabled in a module, it generates a binding class for each XML layout file present in that module. An instance of a binding class contains direct references to all views that have an ID in the corresponding layout.

The Data Binding Library is a support library that allows you to bind UI components in your layouts to data sources in your app using a declarative format rather than programmatically.

**Differences View Binding and Data Binding**

1. View Binding library is faster than Data Binding library as it is
   not utilising annotation processors underneath, and when it comes to
   compile time speed View Binding is more efficient.
2. The one and only function of View Binding is to bind the views in
   the code. While Data Binding offers some more options like Binding
   Expressions, which allows us to write expressions the connect
   variables to the views in the layout.
3. Data Binding library works with Observable Data objects, you don't
   have to worry about refreshing the UI when underlying data changes.
4. Data Binding library provides us with Binding Adapters.
5. Data Binding library provides us with Two way Data Binding, this is
   a technique of binding your objects to xml layouts, so that both
   object and layout can send data to each other.

To understand View Binding and Data Binding in detail you can go through these articles,

https://medium.com/geekculture/android-viewbinding-over-findviewbyid-389401b41706

https://anubhav-arora.medium.com/android-view-binding-v-s-data-binding-5862a27524e9

Answer (score 1):

ViewBinding seems to suffice for smaller/simpler projects. For example, if you are just beginning to learn Android Kotlin, using ViewBinding reduces the amount of repetitive code you need to write---rather than trying to get the reference to the view object using the `findViewById` function, you can simply use the binding object property to access any XML view objects with a declared ID.