# Unresolved reference: binding - Kotlin Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I keep getting the error " Unresolved reference: binding". Does anyone know what I am missing? I already tried updating everything. But the binding won't work.

Build.Gradle.(module.app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.madlevel1example"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true}

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Comment: refer this -->https://stackoverflow.com/a/37044756/12553303

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use dataBinding rather than viewBinding. Altho viewBinding has a shorter build tim. The things Databinding make up for a lot of it.

Refer to this stack link

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58040778/android-difference-between-databinding-and-viewbinding#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20main%20advantages%20of%20viewbinding,processors%20affecting%20databinding's%20build%20time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58040778/android-difference-between-databinding-and-viewbinding#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20main%20advantages%20of%20viewbinding,processors%20affecting%20databinding%27s%20build%20time).