# Android Gradle 4 upgrade issue (aapt, windowEnterAnimationt) -- looks like "aapt2 issue"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When asked to upgrade to the newest Gradle 4.1? (2018-04-14) I get very weird errors I have never seen before. The app runs for years without this issue.

[image]

After searching the complete project again, I did find a @android:attr/windowEnterAnimation, in a place I did not expect.

For appt2 errors? Here is a nice [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47034474/3143823) on how to move forward.

Comment: What did you change in order to update gradle ? Did you change the file `gradle-wrapper.properties` ? Did you try to rollback to the previous version of gradle to see if the compilation runs ok ?

Comment: Did you try by changing your gradle keywords to the replaced ones?
For e.g.: compile to implementation? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!-- When referencing resources from the 'android' namespace, omit the '@' symbol. -->
<item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation"/>
```

**When building the module, AAPT2 now throws the following build error:
Error: style attribute '@android:attr/windowEnterAnimation' not found**

I am quite sure, in some of your animation file you have used '@'. Remove that.

If you use the new gradle, you have to follow the structures and rules properly, this entire details is put in their website. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations

Answer (score -1):

replace "`@android:attr/`" with "`?attr`" maybe it will solve your problem.